# Parsing JSON data into separate fields in Kibana

Tags: json, elasticsearch

We have an EKS cluster and an ELK stack to monitor the cluster. The logs from the cluster is shipped via Fluentbit. The requirement is to make the log message into separate fields in Kibana so that it becomes easier to filter and create dashboards out of it. If supposing the logs are made into a JSON file, could someone suggest a solution to make the key-value pairs in JSON into separate fields in Kibana?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

There are multiple ways to go about it.

- [Logstash json plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html)
- [Filebeat decode json processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/decode-json-fields.html)
- [Elasticsearch ingest pipeline json processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/json-processor.html)

This is not an extensive list, but those are the one I know about.

## Solution

### Ingest pipeline

Create a pipeline

```json
PUT _ingest/pipeline/pipeline_json_parser
{
  "description" : "json parser pipeline",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "json" : {
        "field" : "string_source",
        "target_field" : "json_target"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Test the pipeline

```json
POST /_ingest/pipeline/pipeline_json_parser/_simulate
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "_index": "index",
      "_id": "id",
      "_source": {
        "string_source": "{\"a\":\"b\"}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Set the [pipeline as default on an index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html#set-default-pipeline)

And you are all set.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are there ways to do it via Fluentbit itself?

Comment: Maybe, I do not know